# inheriting object from another class

Tags: c#, mvvm

So currently I have a RadAutocomplete box. I am able to call that object in the

```
public MainWindow()
```

But I want to be able to call it in my viewmodel. If I may get tips and suggestions Would be great.

Comment: what type of object is that? is it control or some logic class ?

Comment: It's a telerik Object on xaml page.

Answer (score 0):

Never in `WPF` create UI elements, like in your case telerik objects, from view model. 
If you do so, you loose benefits of `MVVM`.

View model is for *binding* between UI and business logic itself. You have to define telerik oject in XAML and show/hide it based on model view property.